# How to get commit history of users in gitlab in rails

Tags: ruby, git, ruby-on-rails-5, gitlab

I am trying to create an app which will fetch the gitlab/github commit history of the user which i can just show in a side panel and it can be checked on or off depending on my criteria. I want to know if there is a way to fetch the current logged user's gitlab/github commit history. I tried to use the gem

```
https://github.com/libgit2/rugged
```

But couldn't find a way to implement my need. If anyone knows how to implement this it would be so much helpful. Thanks.

**Update**

I have now managed to get the user by using :

```
Gitlab.endpoint = 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4'
Gitlab.private_token = 'token'
g = Gitlab.client(
  endpoint: 'https://gitlab.com/api/v4',
  private_token: 'token',
  httparty: {
    headers: { 'Cookie' => 'gitlab_canary=true' }
  }
)
```

By using the command `g.user` i am able to get the user but i need to get the commits of the user that he has done in `gitlab`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use this gitlab API `GET /projects/:id/repository/commits` to fetch all the commits on a repository [gitlab api](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html). Check the attached code for more details.
2. Basically this `git log --author="user_name"` command can give you git commit history for a specific user, you can even use email address just the first name or last name in the above command.
3. Once you have authenticated with gitlab you can run the following command from ruby.

```
    cmd = 'git log --author="user_name"'
    system(cmd)
```

- Sample code form ruby to connect to gitlab using private token which is not ideal but just an example

```
require 'json'
require 'curb'
require 'net/http'

begin

 def parseCoverageReport(report_text) 
   coverage_perc = report_text.match /All files\s+\|\s+(\d+\.?\d+).*\n/
   if not coverage_perc then
     coverage_perc = report_text.match /^TOTAL\s+\d+\s+\d+\s+(\d+)%$/
   end

   if coverage_perc then 
     #if we found coverage value in job trace
     #puts "coverage_perc[1]: #{coverage_perc[1]}"
     coverage_perc[1].to_i
   end
 end

 gen_config = YAML.load_file("config/general.yml")
 gitlab_config = YAML.load_file("config/gitlab.yml")

 SCHEDULER.every gen_config[:job_trigger_interval], :first_in => 0 do |job|

 table = {
     title: "Projects",
     hrows: Array.new.push({cols: [
       {value: "Project name"}, 
       {value: "Open Merge Requests"},
       {value: "Code coverage"}
     ]}),
     rows: Array.new
 }

 instances = gitlab_config['instances']

 instances.each do |instance|

   gitlab_url = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['url']
   # gitlab_token = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['api_key']
   gitlab_token = ENV[gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['api_key']]
   red_threshold = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['red_threshold']
   orange_threshold = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['orange_threshold']
   cov_red_threshold = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['cov_red_threshold']
   cov_orange_threshold = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['cov_orange_threshold']
   projects = gitlab_config['instances'][instance.first]['projects']

   projects.each do |name, project|

       merge_reqs = JSON.parse(Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}/merge_requests?state=opened&private_token=#{gitlab_token}&per_page=200").body_str)
       git_project =  JSON.parse(Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}?private_token=#{gitlab_token}").body_str)
       opened_mrs = merge_reqs.select { |merge_reqs| %w[opened].include? merge_reqs['state'] }
       repo_name  = git_project['name']
       repo_url  = git_project['web_url']


       status = case
       when opened_mrs.size >= red_threshold then 'danger'
       when opened_mrs.size >= orange_threshold then 'warning'
       else
         'ok'
       end

       mrs_count = "#{opened_mrs.size}"
       send_event("#{name}_mr", { current: mrs_count, status: status })

       color = case
       when opened_mrs.size >= red_threshold then 'red'
       when opened_mrs.size >= orange_threshold then 'orange'
       else
         'green'
       end

       font_color = color == 'orange' ? 'black' : 'white'

       cov_color = color
       font_cov_color = 'white'

       code_coverage = "---"
       code_coverage_tag = "---"
       cov_job_url = ''

       jobs = JSON.parse(Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}/jobs?scope=success&private_token=#{gitlab_token}&per_page=30").body_str)
       code_cov_job = jobs.find { |gitlab_job| !gitlab_job['coverage'].nil? }

       if not code_cov_job then
         #if no job has 'coverage' feature set up in Gitlab try to parse 
         #'coverage' from jobs trace manually
         jobs.each do |job|
               trace_report = Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}/jobs/#{job['id']}/trace?private_token=#{gitlab_token}").body_str
               code_cov_percentage = parseCoverageReport(trace_report)
               if code_cov_percentage then
                 code_cov_job = job
                 code_cov_job['coverage'] = code_cov_percentage
                 break 
               end
         end
       end

       if code_cov_job then
         #found code coverage data => process them
         code_coverage = code_cov_job['coverage'].to_i
         cov_job_url = code_cov_job['web_url'].to_s

         #update code covergate SprintProgress widgets at the same job
         widget_title = "code_coverage_progress_#{project['id']}"
         send_event(widget_title, { 
           title: "Code Coverage - #{git_project['name']}", 
           sprintboard_url: cov_job_url,
           min: 0, 
           max: 100, 
           value: code_coverage, 
           moreinfo: ''
         })

         cov_color = case
         when code_coverage <= cov_red_threshold then 'red'
         when code_coverage <= cov_orange_threshold then 'orange'
         else
           'green'
         end

         code_coverage = "#{code_coverage}%"
         code_coverage_tag = "<a href='#{cov_job_url}' target='_blank'>#{code_coverage.to_s}</a>"
       end

       repo_name_a_tag = "<a href='#{repo_url}' target='_blank'>#{repo_name}</a>"
       open_mrs_size = "<a href='#{repo_url}/merge_requests' target='_blank'>#{opened_mrs.size}</a>"

       table[:rows].push({ 
         cols: [
           { value: repo_name_a_tag, style: "color: #{font_color}; background-color: #{color}" }, 
           { value: open_mrs_size, style: "color: #{font_color}; background-color: #{color}" },
           { value: code_coverage_tag, style: "color: #{cov_color == 'orange' ? 'black' : 'white'}; background-color: #{cov_color}" } 
         ]
       })

     end
   end

   send_event('open_merge_requests_table', table)

end
rescue Errno::ENOENT
 puts "No config file found for gitlab - not starting the Gitlab job"
end
```

- In the above ruby example please have a look at the following code snippet

```
merge_reqs = JSON.parse(Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}/merge_requests?state=opened&private_token=#{gitlab_token}&per_page=200").body_str)
       git_project =  JSON.parse(Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}?private_token=#{gitlab_token}").body_str)
       opened_mrs = merge_reqs.select { |merge_reqs| %w[opened].include? merge_reqs['state'] }
       repo_name  = git_project['name']
       repo_url  = git_project['web_url']
```

In here what i am trying to do is connect to our gitlab instance using a private_token and then for a specific project id (which you can get it form the UI of gitlab) check for the open merge request. I also get the git_project from which i get the name and web_url (which was my use case).

- For your use case you will have to get the project_id(for gitlab UI) and then use some appropriate method to get the commits.[gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/README.html#personal-access-tokens)

Comment: Is this ```gitlab.Gitlab('https://git.xxx.xxx.xxx', private_token='xxxxxxxxxx')``` associated with this gem? I need to get log of all the commits of the user from all projects will this work for that ?

Comment: @amal I have updated my answer its using a ruby code to connect to gitlab using  private token. JSON.parse(Curl.get("#{gitlab_url}/api/v4/projects/#{project['id']}/jobs?scope=success&private_token=#{gitlab_token}&per_page=30").body_str)

Comment: Sorry to ask but can you give a simpler example ?

Comment: With your help i have managed to get the user from gitlab but i don't know how to get the user's commit history. This code that you specified 
```cmd = 'git log --author="user_name"'
    system(cmd)```
works for the system but i can't manipulate it to get the contents of the commit.

Comment: @Amal I have updated the answer, hope the last 2 points are helpful to you

Comment: I am getting a namerror for the Curl.get command how to fix this i installed the gem ```curl and curb``` but still shows the same. I am somewhere close but need to get this curl working.

Comment: @Amal worth checking your ruby version, gem version if you are installing it correctly https://github.com/taf2/curb

Comment: @ammittn Got it working but the result is only returning the first record of a result

Comment: @ammittn For eg if try to get the contents from this link ```https://gitlab.com/api/v4/users/root/events/``` I am only getting the first index record. This has only 1 record in 0 index but i mean i need to get all the records in that link

Comment: @amal you should be using this endpoint to get all the commits GET /projects/:id/repository/commits refer this page https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/commits.html . Once you get the json you will have to iterate over and get the specific commits for a user. Note that you will have to get the project Id from the UI

Comment: @amal if all the above has been helpful, can you please accept the answer

Comment: Thanks for the help ! I am somewhat close to achieve my goal thanks to you.